# writing from textbox to text file C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write from textboxes in windows form to textfile, I want to use the spilt. I want to be written in the text file like this

Namelabel : NametextBox
passlabel : PasstextBox

how can I do that!

```
StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Register.txt")

            txt.Write(Namelabel.Text);
            txt.WriteLine(NametextBox.Text);
            txt.Write(passlabel.Text);
            txt.WriteLine(PasstextBox.Text);
```

Comment: You can simply use [`System.IO.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) to write text in file.

Comment: but how can I to write the label and textbox in same line and splited  by :

Comment: I posted a sample for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`System.IO.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) to write text in file. For example:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\Register.txt", 
    string.Format("{0}:{1}\n{2}:{3}"
        Namelabel.Text,
        NametextBox.Text
        passlabel.Text
        PasstextBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there:

```
using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Register.txt"))
{
    txt.Write(Namelabel.Text);
    txt.WriteLine(NametextBox.Text);
    txt.Write(passlabel.Text);
    txt.WriteLine(PasstextBox.Text);
}
```

You might want to make it a bit easier to read by using string.Format:

```
using (StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Register.txt"))
{
    txt.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", Namelabel.Text, NametextBox.Text));
    txt.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", passlabel.PasstextBox, NametextBox.Text));
}
```